# Open folder using prolog

Tags: prolog, directory

Does anyone know how to open every file in a folder in prolog (like you can open a single file)? I'm very new to prolog and have a folder full of folders which in turn are full of files that I need to open. Thanks for any ideas!

Comment: Which Prolog implementation are you using? If you're using SWI Prolog, see the SWI documentation on [File System Interaction](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=files)

Comment: there are a lot of answers to your question in differents ways ,
but for me, the [DCG](http://www.metalevel.at/prolog/dcg.html) is the most elegant